# How can I change the visibility of a div through the click event of a button or link that is on another page (html) in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, web

How can I change the visibility of a div through the click event of a button or link that is on another page (html)? I have a button on the "main.html" page that I want, which when I click, it displays a hidden div in "header.html". Is there a way for me to do this?

I have in index.html:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default px-4" [routerLink]="['../home']" (click)="">Entrar</button>`

And in Header.html:

```
            `<div class="page">
              Olá {{'usuario'}}, seja bem vindo! Hoje é dia {{today | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
            </div>`
```

The div that is in header.html must be hidden and when I click the button that is in index.html it should be displayed.

Comment: can you post some code? it would help if we could know how the header component is called in the main component, if main component is the parent you could do this with angular by using EventEmitter for example

Comment: You can use `@EventEmitter` or `Subject` to let two components communicate. Here's a simple stackblitz working with Subject: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vts7zd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.component.ts

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is that you emit an event wherever the button is:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'btn-component',
    template: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default px-4" [routerLink]="['../home']" (click)="buttonClicked()"> Entrar </button> `
})
export class ButtonComponent {
    @Output() buttonClickedEvent = new EventEmitter();
    public buttonClicked() { // You can give any function name
        this.buttonClickedEvent.emit("click!");
    }
}
```

and then you catch it at the 'div' level:

```
`<div class="page" [hidden]="!showDiv" (buttonClickedEvent)='showDiv = !showDiv'>
      Olá {{'usuario'}}, seja bem vindo! Hoje é dia {{today | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
</div>`
```

See more about event emitters [here](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular)

Comment: I did as he suggested. I created a button.component, made the import of it in the app.module and used it on the screen as <btn-component>. It appears the Enter button, when I click it it calls the Home page, however I can not make the div appear hidden and appear when I click Enter.